# Numeric precision for log(1-exp(x))

Tags: statistics, probability, numerical-methods

I'm doing some math with really big numbers (I'm using Python, but this question isn't Python specific). For one value, I have a formula that gives me `f(t) = Pr(X < t)`. I want to use this formula to get `Pr(X >= t) = 1 - f(t)`. Because `f(t)` returns values very close to zero, I've been using a log transform and storing `log( f(t) )` instead of `f(t)`. My `log( f(t) )` is on the order of -1e5 or so.

For multiplying, this works quite well. `log( f(t) * g ) = log( f(t) ) + log(g)`.

But, it's very difficult to compute `log( 1 - f(t) )` using only `log( f(t) )`; I could, of course, temporarily exponentiate the value I store and compute `log( 1 - exp( log( f(t) ) )`, but that will return `log( 1 - 0.0 ) = 0.0` because `log( f(t) )` is so close to zero.

You might ask, "Why do you care? If it's close to zero, then 1 minus it is very close to 1." Well, that's a good point you've made. You're a smart cookie.

The trouble is I want to use this to rank values, so I really care if one is `log(0.999)` and the other is `log(0.9999)`. You might also ask, "Well, why don't you just rank the `log( f(t) )` and then reverse the order to get the rankings for `log( 1 - f(t) )`." Again, I cannot help but point out how great your questions are. It really has been a pleasure talking to you.

But here's the problem: I don't just want to rank by `1 - f(t)`; I actually want to rank based on `Pr(X >= t) * g(t) = (1 - f(t)) g(t)`. After taking logs, I get `log( 1 - f(t) ) + log( g(t) )`; ranking based on `f(t)` alone won't give the correct answer.

In the past I wrote a little Python function to compute `log(a + b)` from `log(a)` and `log(b)`:

```
def log_add(logA,logB):
    if logA == log(0):
        return logB
    if logA<logB:
        return log_add(logB,logA)
    return log( 1 + math.exp(logB-logA) ) + logA
```

It helps by first normalizing them so that they're close together and then exponentiating when they're close together.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get the same trick to work for my subtraction because there is no normalization factor that will bring `log(1)` and `log( f(t) )` close together because they're so far apart.

Does anyone know how to solve this? It seems like such a classic kind of problem; I'd really expect/hope/pray that there is a clever function that operates on the bit level that can give me `log(1-x)` from `log(x)`. Also, if you know *how* it works, I'd really, really love to know.

Cheers!
Oliver

Comment: The taylor series for x->log(1-x) is -(x + x^2/2 + .. x^n/n + ..). With the range of x's you have, to distinguish -x from log(1-x) you'd need to use ~1.4e5 bits, so perhaps you could approximate log(1-x) by -x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `log(f(t))` is indeed -1e5 (or of similar order of magnitude) then 0.0 is the best floating point representation of `log(1-f(t))`. Indeed, `f(t) = exp(-1e5)` so, by the Taylor series that dmuir mentioned, `log(1-f(t)) = -exp(-1e5)` (this is actually not an exact equality, but it is an extremely good approximation). Now, `-exp(-1e5) = -3.56e-43430`, but there are no floating point numbers between 0 and -4e-324, so the best floating point representation is 0.0.

So, what you want to do is impossible with standard floating point numbers.

Does this matter? You say that want to rank based on `Pr(X >= t) * g(t) = (1 - f(t)) g(t)`, which is equivalent to ranking by `log( 1 - f(t) ) + log( g(t) )`. We found above that `log(1-f(t)) = -3.56e-43430`, so this term is only going to make a difference if the different values of `log(g(t))` differ by no more than this tiny number and if your computation is accurate enough that it can distinguish by these tiny numbers (if you use standard floating point numbers, then your computation will never be accurate enough). In other words, if `log(f(t))` is indeed -1e5 or similar, than you can just rank by `g(t)`.

However, it may be that `log(f(t))` is of the order of -1e5, but that it sometimes takes values closer to zero like -10 or -1. In that case, you cannot just ignore it and you have to indeed rank by `log(1-f(t)) + log(g(t))`. You should write this using the [`math.log1p`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.log1p) function: rank by `log1p(-f(t)) + log(g(t))`. The reason is that if f(t) is close to zero, then `log(1-f(t))` is inaccurate but `log1p(-f(t))` is accurate. If f(t) is extremely close to zero, such as when `log(f(t)) = -1e5`, then `log1p(-f(t)) = 0.0` because that is the best it can do using standard floating point numbers.

I am using the expression "standard floating point numbers" for a reason. It is possible to use floating point numbers with more precision, and if you really want to capture tiny numbers like `-3.56e-43430` that is what you should do. One possibility is in Python is [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) (unfortunately, it does not seem to support the `log1p` function). Be warned that this is much slower than standard floating point numbers, and as I said I don't think you'll need it. However, it's worth a go if you want to understand these issues better.

Comment: +1 Thanks, great ideas. I could use high precision for that step alone. Or possibly just use the Taylor expansion for log(1-exp(x)).